# Selenium. NoSuchElementException

Tags: python, html, selenium, html-parsing

can someone be able to understand what the problem of this code is?I understand that the question is not new, but what I found just didn't help me, but maybe I was looking badly

```
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=chrome_options)
    wd.get('https://www.uniprot.org/uniprotkb/Q14050/entry')
    sleep(15)
    Molmass = wd.find_element('xpath','//*[@id="sequences"]/div/div[2]/section/ul/li[2]/div/div[2]')
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="decorated-list-item__content">63,616</div>
```

Selector:

```
#sequences > div > div.card__content > section > ul > li:nth-child(2) > div > div.decorated-list-item__content
```

XPATH:

```
//*[@id="sequences"]/div/div[2]/section/ul/li[2]/div/div[2]
```

Error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="sequences"]/div/div[2]/section/ul/li[2]/div/div[2]"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=107.0.5304.87)
```

I tried searching by class, selectors, xpath, but nothing helps, I tried to set a timer so that the page had time to load, but there was no result

Comment: One obvious answer is that the given xpath value is wrong.  Where did you get that value?

Comment: @JohnGordon I took this link from the site https://www.uniprot.org/uniprotkb/Q14050/entry in the 'Sequence' section there is Mas (Da) = 63.616, I took exactly the html link to Mas (Da)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are trying the get the value '`63,616`', for that you can use any one of the below locators:

CSS_SELECTOR:

```
 driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".sequence-container li:nth-of-type(2) .decorated-list-item__content").text
```

XPATH:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//section[@class='sequence-container']//li[2]//div[@class='decorated-list-item__content']").text
```

Comment: The same NoSuchElementException error still occurs, but thanks for the answer anyway

Comment: That element is loaded when you scroll down on that page, add the code for scroll down and check, that element will be available.